# Getting $df(t,T)$ when given $d\ln P(t,T)$ and $f(t,T)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln P(t,T)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, heath-jarrow-morton

Let the HJM dynamics of $\ln P(t,T)$ (log of bond prices) given by (In the risk neutral measure ) :

$$d \ln P(t,T) = \mathcal{O}( dt) - \sigma_P (t,T) dW(t)$$

Knowing that $f(t,T)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln P(t,T)$ I want to compute $df(t,T)$. (The dynamics of the instantaneous forward rate)

For that I tried applying Itô, but I'm stuck at defining the variables driving $f(t,T)$. I usually define a $\phi$ depending on time and the random variable and then apply Itô. But here I'm confused as I could choose time being $t$ or $T$.

So my first question is : what is the rule of thumb for defining $\phi$ to which I apply Itô?

My second question : is applying Itô the right way to get $df(t,T)$ ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to treat $t$ and $T$ as independent. That is, for differential with respect $t$, you can treat $T$ as a constant.

Comment: @Gordon could you show how to get $df(t,T)$ by computation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that 
\begin{align*}
d \ln P(t,T) = \mu(t, T) dt - \sigma (t,T) dW(t).
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\ln P(t,T) = \ln P(0,T) + \int_0^t \mu(s, T) ds - \int_0^t \sigma (s,T) dW(s).
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
f(t, T) &= -\frac{\partial\ln P(t,T)}{\partial T} \\
&= -\frac{\partial\ln P(0,T)}{\partial T} - \int_0^t \frac{\partial\mu(s, T)}{\partial T} ds + \int_0^t \frac{\partial\sigma (s,T)}{\partial T} dW(s),
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
d f(t,T) = \frac{\partial\mu(t, T)}{\partial T} dt + \frac{\partial\sigma (t,T)}{\partial T} dW(t).
\end{align*}

Note that, under the risk-neutral probability measure, 
\begin{align*}
\mu(t, T) = r_t - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 (t,T).
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
d f(t,T) = \sigma(t, T)\frac{\partial\sigma(t, T)}{\partial T} dt + \frac{\partial\sigma (t,T)}{\partial T} dW(t).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you that is quite helpful !!! one last question. It looks like that my first thought of applying Itô is not a good idea. Could you tell me how could I avoid the same mistake in the future? I mean why didn't you apply Itô?

Comment: I apply Ito when needed.

Comment: And when is that needed?

Comment: I think you still need to read the book, for example, the book [Stochastic Calculus for Finance II](https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-II-Continuous-Time/dp/144192311X) by Shreve.